# Is it possible to use Bayesian networks to predict numerical values? (non-categorical)

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

Is it possible to use Bayesian networks to predict numerical values? (non-categorical)

For example is it possible to build a Bayesian network in the case of a house price prediction? I found answers for categorical model predictions but not numeric ones...

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: A bayesian network is just a representation of dependencies between random variables - regardless of what distributions they follow. So I don't see any conceptual /theoretical hurdles to having some follow discrete distributions and others follow continuous ones. Not sure what off-the-shelf software would implement though.

Answer (score 1):

I am building one right now.  Bayesian networks just define associations that must exist.  They can be used to predict anything that is predictable.  Your model must make sense, but assuming it does you just need to determine proper likelihood functions.

That said, I am hand building everything.  If you step outside the standard process the usefulness of packages can fall apart.

**EDIT**

I thought I would provide an example.  Consider the case where a binary (or multinomial) choice is made, each of which result in other possible choices.  However, at the end of the chain may be the total number of gallons of gas consumed if the decision is to drive, for another it is the price of an airline ticket, for another it is price of an airline ticket plus the cost of lodging, for yet another it estimates the travel time on an airline plus Eurorail.  Your base nodes could be regressions.